# Regex pattern for detecting injectable part of android string resources

Tags: java, regex

Android localisable string resources are stored in xml. This is not really relevant, but sometimes there are some special patterns like:

`%n$t` - Where `n` is always integer and `t`might be s, d or f (basically single alphabhet letter). Examples below:

```
%1$s
%5$s
%45$s
%2$f
%3$d
%11$d
```

What would be the **regex pattern** I could use to replace matching part of String with another one?

My expected results would be:

```
{s}
{s}
{s}
{n}
{n}
{n}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
"%\\d+\\$[sdf]"
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your updates, you want to replace the entire matching string

```
"%\\d+\\$[a-zA-Z]"
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] strings = {
        "Test %1$s",
        "Test %5$s",
        "Test %45$s",
        "Test %2$f",
        "Test %3$d",
        "Test %11$d"
    };

    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string.replaceFirst("%\\d+\\$[a-zA-Z]", "something"));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Test something
Test something
Test something
Test something
Test something
Test something
```

Comment: Not exactly, updated the question with expected results